# How to automate the process of running an excel model, 100,000 times, with different inputs in Python?

Tags: python, excel, automation

So I have a complex financial model on excel for a given set of input. Now I want to run the same model on 100,000 other sets of input and save it. Is there any libraries I should look into? I just have to change the inputs. Any guidance will be appreciated. TIA!

Comment: there are many options to build models using python, you'd have to explain more on the model you are trying to build/copy, is it a machine learning one? if so - please google 'python machine learning ecosystem' for libraries such as 'numpy', 'pandas', 'pytorch' etc

Comment: @a.k Its a simple automation process. The excel model accepts inputs and displays outputs. All I have to do is give that excel model 100,000 different inputs and it should give me 100,000 different outputs. Just have to do in a time efficient manner. The excel model itself is complex involving multiple sheets and various complex formulai and calculations but we shouldnt be worried about that.

Comment: Hi, your question is too general, please review this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand what kind of questions we resolve on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar job with openxyl, but it doesn't like conditional formatting

you can write read, change the size of the boxes change the color and even invoke graphs with data

you can do almost anything

Comment: Using openpyxl, I have this process in mind. I open the model, change the input values, save the file. Loop it 100,000 times for all input sets. Would this be feasible in terms of time etc?